# get checked items from listview in android

Tags: android

I have a dynamic listview with one text and one checkbox per line.when i click a button.,i need to get all checked item names & Unchecked item names separately as arraylilst.How could i do that.Examples are much better..

I used..

```
    SparseBooleanArray checked = mainlw.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {

        if(checked.valueAt(i) == true) {
            Planet tag = (Planet) mainlw.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));

            String selectedName=tag.getName();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this out and implement this logic according to your requirement.

```
int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

String checked = "";

String unchecked = "";
SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();

for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++)
{

     if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
     {
         checked += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
     }
     else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
     {
         unchecked+= myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
     }

 }
```

Comment: Can anyone please tell me that how the :check" is donw in list , by long clicking it or any other way ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

use **CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE** in your `ListView` and use `getCheckedItemPositions()` to get the checked ones.

Comment: its working fine.Its getting selected names.But how could i get Unchecked names too?

Comment: if you want the names of both checked and unchecked items just use `getCount()` and `getItemAtPosition(int position)`. you could iterate through the items and add them to your ArrayList. see

[getCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getCount()) and
[getItemAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int))

Answer (score 0):

So Onclick of button u can do this,From this you will get the items that are checked:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
        System.out.println("check"+getListView().getCheckItemIds().length);

        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getCheckItemIds().length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(getListView().getAdapter().getItem((int)getListView().getCheckItemIds()[i]).toString());                 
        }   

}
```

Comment: i used..    SparseBooleanArray checked = mainlw.getCheckedItemPositions();
           for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
               if(checked.valueAt(i) == true) {
                Planet tag = (Planet) mainlw.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));
                String selectedName=tag.getName();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: From that i can get checked items well.But how could i get Unchecked itemm too separately