# Android :How to count no checked items of checkboxes in listview

Tags: android

Android :How to count no checked items of checkboxes in listview when using Simple cursor Adapter

Answer (score 4):

[Call `getCheckedItemCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemCount%28%29) on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
                int cntChoice = listView.getCount();
                String checked = "";
                String unchecked = "";
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++)
                {

                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
                    {
                      //  checked = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() ;
                        checked= list1.get(i).toString();

                        Log.i("CheckedItem", checked);
                    }
                    else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
                    {
                        //unchecked= listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                        unchecked= list1.get(i).toString();

                        Log.i("uncheckedItem", unchecked);
                    }


                }
```

Hope this will help you. For more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726923/1835764).