# How to display Strings from ArrayList in TextView

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, textview

I need to display current values in TextView (after removing String).
I'm adding String when button is On and I need to remove it, when it's Off ( I don't know if I do it well), next I need to display Strings in TextView without deleted String. I need to display only Strings from On buttons.
Here is my code:

```
public class Calc extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        display.setText("Add item");
    }

    static boolean isempty=true;

    public void changeButton(View sender) {
    ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) sender;

    ArrayList<String> mActiveToggles = new ArrayList<String>();

    String b = btn.getText().toString();

    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) sender).isChecked();

    if(on) {
        if (isempty) {
            if (b.equals("0")) return;
            display.setText(btn.getText());
            mActiveToggles.add(b);
            isempty = false;
        } else {
            display.append(btn.getText());
            mActiveToggles.add(b);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (b.equals(btn.getText()))
        {
            mActiveToggles.remove(b);
            display.setText(mActiveToggles.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We could help you better if you actually explain what the specific problem is that you are having.

Comment: @codeMagic I just edited, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit based on new information:

To display the texts from all the toggles that are currently ON in your `TextView` I suggest that you create a

```
private ArrayList<String> mActiveToggles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Whenever a toggle button is set to ON, you add the label of that toggle button to the list. Whenever a toggle button is set to OFF, you remove the label from the list.

```
if(on) {
    if (b.equals("0")) return; // Don't really know why you need this one...

    // If the button is ON, add its text label to the list.
    mActiveToggles.add(btn.getText());
} else {
    // If button is OFF, remove its text label from the list.
    mActiveToggles.remove(btn.getText());
}
```

To update your `TextView` simple iterate over the items in the list and add them to the `TextView` (with an appropriate separator). Something like this:

```
StringBuilder allLabels = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : mActiveToggles) {
    if(allLabels.length() > 0) {
        allLabels.append(" "); // some divider between the different texts
    }
    allLabels.append(s);
}
display.setText(allLabels.toString());
```

If you really do need the content of your `TextView` to be persistently stored, iterate over the list items and concatenate them and then store them to your `SharedPreferences` object. Restoring them from storage would simply be the reverse operation of splitting the String and populating the list. Based on the code that you've provided I don't see a need for this, but there could of course be more to it than what you've posted here.

Comment: It doesn't work, because it clears everything and setText to button wich is Off. I need to display Strings from buttons wich are On.

Comment: well in that case just move the line where you set the text to be above the line where you remove it.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've just read that key can store only one value if it's true it can't work. Maybe some other ideas?

Comment: Yes you can only store one value. If you want to store multiple values you'll have to explain a bit more in detail what values you want to store and how to use them. You could e.g. chain the values valueA|valueB|valueC in your SharedPReferences entry. But I doubt that it's the best way. Right now there's just too many question marks for me to provide a good solution.

Comment: Seriously I want to do something like opposite to append and I'm looking for solution. My app is about adding items to TextView when ToggleButton is On, but when it's Off - String from ToggleButton needs to be removed from TextView. There would be a lot of buttons, so I only want to remove name from a button which is Off. For example when buttons are On it can show ToggleButton1+ToggleButton2+ToggleButton3, but if ToggleButton2 is Off, TextView will show ToggleButton1+ToggleButton3

Comment: I've edited my question. Could you tell me how to display ArrayList in TextView? display.setText(mActiveToggles.toString()); doesn't work.

Comment: It has made display empty :(

Comment: I found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726272/get-checked-items-from-listview-in-android but it's for ListView

Comment: Well that solution could be applied to your problem too. I've added some more sample code for you. I'm not going to write the whole thing for you. :) You still need to use my examples and put them together yourself. That's how you learn.

Answer (score 0):

For getting strings from shared preferences you have to use :

```
if(sharedpreferences.contains(key_value)){
textview.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(key_value, null));
}
```

If there any issue you get please let me know.

Comment: Please check my actual code, because sharedpreferences only can store one value. I still don't know how to do it right.

Comment: If you are storing values rather than single value than sharedprefrence is not a good idea go for sqlite database.