# How to get checked ids at ListView via Kotlin?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I try to get checked items from my ListView:

```
 val lvPlayers = findViewById(R.id.ListViewAllPlayers) as ListView;
    lvPlayers.choiceMode = ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE;
    lvPlayers.adapter = adapter

    lvPlayers.setOnItemClickListener { 
            adapterView: AdapterView<*>, view1: View, i: Int, l: Long ->
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,lvPlayers.checkedItemCount.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        var checked = lvPlayers.checkedItemIds;
        SharedData.SelectedPlayers.clear();
        for (ch in checked) {
            SharedData.SelectedPlayers.add(players.get(ch.toInt()));
        }
    }
```

But it does not work for me.
I tried to use the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726272/get-checked-items-from-listview-in-android), but as I understand, Kotlin can not iterate over `SparseBooleanArray`.

So, can you help me to get checked ids of ListView?
Should I somehow create an extension method to iterate over `SparseBooleanArray`?
Or, maybe some other way?

Comment: Your code's formatting is off. Please fix

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/19414593/2392960

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the array by its index with:

```
for (i in 0..a.size()-1) {
    //access to a[i]
}
```

See also [ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) and [for loop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops)

**Edited 27th March 2017:**

You can use also [Collection<*>.indices](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) that is the equivalent

```
for (i in a.indices) {
    //access to a[i]
}
```

Comment: you forgot the `size - 1`

Answer (score 1):

> i understand, Kotlin can not iterate over `SparseBooleanArray`

Kotlin's `for` can iterate through anything, if it provides `iterator()`, be it a method or an extension function. Here are the [details](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops).

You can implement `SparseBooleanArray#iterator` as an extension function and have you code working.